# Try - catch return method

Tags: java

Is this syntax best method?

```
method 1:
   input
   method2():
method2: (input)
   try
   catch
      return(method1())
method3: (input)
   ....
```

This is so when an exception is thrown you rarely want the program to crash, so it's best to have a return statement so the user can declare a new input for the variable. I am reading my textbook for class and they don't cover a return. Otherwise, without the return, having a try-catch seems pointless if the program just terminates.

Comment: Basically, you catch the exception if you know how to handle it. Otherwise throw it and let the caller worry about it. You can catch and throw a different exception if that's part of the contract of course.

Comment: Is this about Java? Then why don't you post Java code?

Comment: Sometimes you don't want to catch exceptions. It may be better to fail fast than to assume you got something valid (DB connection, file handle, result of some complex calculation) and then crash later.

Comment: (yes java, b/c I was lazy and decided to stick with minimal pseudo code, I'm a networker, what can I say :/ ) 
Right, some exceptions you don't want the program to do anything and you want it crash, however, lets say it's the wrong filename. You don't want the user to have to reload the entire program again. Why not just return it back to the inputed method until the file is valid? ... Situations where you don't want the program to crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is simply vulnerable bacaues it can easily go stackoverflow by a malicious user's repeated inputs that cause the exception in method2.

How about this:

```
method 1:
  while
    input
    try
        return method2(input)
    catch
method2: (input)
    return (some result)
method3: (input)
   ....
```

Comment: So it's actually safer and less vulnerable to crash the program as a whole and have the user start over?

Comment: As others wrote, you should catch the exception outside of method2 and handle it in a better way than recursive call.

Comment: ahh okay okay, the reason I went with recursion is because I am ignorant to the method of returning back to the beginning if something fails. That was the only thing I could think of...

Comment: Not really, I just want them to have to do the try statement over again until it's right

Answer (score 0):

If a piece of code is in an authorative position to know exactly what to do with an exception, it can catch it and do whatever that is.

If it's not, it should throw it up to allow a higher level piece of code handle it.  Sometimes it necessary to wrap such an exception in order to keep things at the same level of abstraction as the method call.

At the top level, when there is an exception no code can handle, it's up to a person to deal with it.  You log the exception and apologize to the user.

Answer (score 0):

The exception can be caught in the calling code.

Say you're reading a file in a method

```
Data readFile(String filename) {
  try {
    // Open file here
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // something has happened but you caught it here itself.
    // Caller of this method may not know that.
  }
}
```

Instead if your method throws an exception (Predefined or your custom):

```
Data readFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
   // Open file here. If file name wrong, it throws a FileNotFoundException
}
```

This time the calling code knows that the method may throw an exception and thus, handle it the way it wants.

for e.g.

```
Data data = null;
while(data == null) {
  try {
    String f = /*Some code to read a string from input*/;
    data = readFile(f);
  } catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Unable to read. " + e);
  }
}
```

Ofcourse, there are other ways to do it.

Comment: I think this is close, basically from the catch I want it to restart. So instead of what @WW said, which is to basically apologize and log then close and reopen; I want it to just be like "okay no problem, go type it again". 
It sends you back up to the TRY or to another method to retype the file name. If it's right it will go through the try and skip the catch, not returning you, but continuing on with the application. Never actually halting the user; effectively increasing QoS.

Comment: It's your requirements, but I'd suggest to not use a full on infinite loop for getting the user input. Have some maximum no. of tries and if still unsuccessful, fail and report to the caller of this method or to the user (and probably log it).

Comment: okay, that's a cool idea, I didn't think of that. Another person said it would be a security flaw.

Comment: I'm actually new to programming, so a lot of the jargon goes over my head and it takes me a little longer to understand the meaning. Thank you for your input :)